# DateTimePicker displays today's date instead of displaying its actual Value

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, winforms

We have a couple of DateTimePickers on a custom UserControl, on a Form. They are visible, but not enabled (for display purposes only). When the UserControl is loading, the DateTimePickers are assigned values from a DataRow that came from a DataSet which stores a single record returned from a SQL Server stored procedure.

There is an inconsistent behavior in which the users sometimes see today's date instead of the date that was assigned to the DateTimePicker. It doesn't seem to matter whether I assign the date I want to the .Value property or the .Text property:

```
txtstart.Value = (DateTime) dr["Group_Start_Date"];
txtend.Text = dr["Term_Date"].ToString();
```

I expect that of the two statements above, the one using the Value property is more appropriate. But, in both cases, today's date is displayed to the user regardless of the values that were in the database. In the case of txtstart.Value, Visual Studio shows me that the value was assigned as expected. So why isn't it displaying that date to the user instead of today's date?

Comment: If the DateTimePicker ecnounters an empty or null value, it will display today's date.

Comment: Well if the DateTimePicker is *always* disabled why not use a textbox instead ?

Comment: Actually I have switched these to textboxes as I couldn't determine why a the disabled control was there in the first place. But the point remains. If I assign a value to a DateTimePicker in code, that's the value I expect to see at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with AB Nolan's suggestion. The reasoning behind a disabled DateTimePicker was never clear to me, so back on 10/23/2009, rather than continue fussing with the control I just displayed the dates I wanted in TextBoxes instead.

Answer (score 17):

I found the answer.  You MUST set the checkbox value to checked to indicate a non-null value.

this.dateSold.Checked = true;
// set to true or false, as desired
this.dateSold.ShowCheckBox = false;

Comment: As the asker of the question, I can't really confirm whether this is true as I ended up following AB Kolan's suggestion and just using textbox. But if this worked for someone else, then great.

Comment: I confirm that the `Checked` property appears to be the problem. It may contain a value of `false` even though it was set to `true` in the designer.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of problems with this control. Going by answers "Checked=false" seems to be the most common. For me, it was having the control inside a custom control. unwrapping the custom control fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this too and  found that you indeed need to set the `.Checked` value to `True`.

I set the `Checked` property in the properties window and it still didn't work so I just set it in code before assigning the value and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with having multiple DateTimePickers. I was able to get around the issue (bug?) by programatically creating the DateTimePickers with the values I wanted and adding them to the form.