# Change value of DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm having problem to change the displayed value of my `DateTimePicker` object in C# Winforms

I'm trying to change the date in the `DateTimePicker` according to the value, but the display won't change.

```
dtpDisplayTo.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Is this Winforms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET?

Comment: Works fine for me in Winforms.

Comment: Maybe you should try calling the Update or Refresh methods? Perhaps the form isn't redrawing the control with the updated value.

Comment: Also do add as where exactly are you writing this code

Comment: I don't think it's WPF since the Control there is called `DatePicker`.
And there's no property called `Value`, but a property called `SelectedDate`. --> `dtp.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;` works fine in WPF.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information, its winforms

Comment: the value of the datetimepicker is the currect value (today) but it displays the older one...

Answer (score 4):

I know this is dated, but I just had the same problem and found a solution with a bit of research. You have to set the `Checked` property of the DateTimePicker to **True** before changing the date, otherwise the control will consider the change as null and not show the new date. Really strange stuff.

[DateTimePicker displays today's date instead of displaying its actual Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615294/datetimepicker-displays-todays-date-instead-of-displaying-its-actual-value)